# javascript page referncing

Tags: javascript

is there anyway to findout from which page we entered the current page in javascript? that is if we reached page2 from from page1 ,how can i findout whether i the parent of page2 was page1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.referrer`:

```
var origin = document.referrer;
alert("You came from " + origin);
```

Comment: You should be careful about the referrer concept--it can be altered and is sometimes not correct. however, if you're talking about going from a page on your site to another page on your site it's probably a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.referrer` property:

```
var rf = document.referrer;
alert('You came from:' + rf);
```

More Info:

- http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/javascript_no14.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try using browser history to access more than one page.

document.referrer points just to the last item.